# Is it possible to show / hide part of canvas image like Image Sprite?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to show / hide part of canvas image like Image Sprite ?

Example Case:

I have a canvas of 200 X 200 dimension.

On One button click i want to show part of canvas from point (100, 100) to (120, 120).
On another i want to show entire canvas.

Any help in how to do this?

Comment: What should happen to the parts of the canvas that were not shown?

Comment: Just take the part of the canvas you want to show, wipe everything, and then draw it where you want it.

Comment: I am creating the Image like http://jsfiddle.net/5cau08n6/

When user clicks on center circle i want to toggle the full canvas.

Comment: @Srinivas, After combining your comments on this question and your duplicate follow-on question, I must unfortunately let you know that the element chosen by you (html5 canvas) is not suitable for your exact requirements. You want to show/hide individual elements on the canvas without clearing the canvas. Drawings on html5 canvas cannot be shown & hidden individually because the canvas retains no reference to any individual drawing that it has already drawn onto its surface. The canvas cannot meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As sprite are usually shown within another element as a background, perhaps hiding the parent element would take care of your problem?

```
<style>
    #sprite {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: src(sprite.png); 
        background-position: 100px 100px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var hide = false;

    function show() {
        if(!hide) {
            document.getElementById("sprite").style.width="200px";
            hide = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("sprite").style.width="100px";
            hide = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="button" onclick="show();">button</div>
<div id="sprite"></div>
```

This is if the sprite's position is 100px to the right. You could also use `document.getElementById('#sprite').style.backgroundPosition="200px 200px";` to change position of the sprite background entirely.

Comment: here i am not dealing the image sprite.
i am working the Canvas Image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clipping form of drawImage to display your desired portion of the full image:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/cats.png";
function start(){
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,78,86, 0,0,78,86);

  document.getElementById('partial').onclick=function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,78,86, 0,0,78,86);
  }

  document.getElementById('full').onclick=function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<button id='partial'>Show partial canvas</button>
<button id='full'>Show full canvas</button>
<br><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: but mine was not an single image to cilp and redraw single.
I can creating that canvas dynamically with multiple circles which will get changed by user input.

you can see the Canvas image when user entered 5 

http://jsfiddle.net/5cau08n6/.

Comment: @Srinivas I thought I understood your question until I saw your comment above. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: When i am loading the page i am creating a canvas with 5 outer circles along with one center.

I want to implement like first i will show only center circle of canvas.
when user click on center circle i want to show all the outer circles.
when user clicks again the center circle i want to hide all outer circles.

did you got that?

Comment: @Srinivas - Check out my edit. Its exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: No..your clearing and drawing the canvas again. I don't want to do that. i want to do in Show / Hide manner

Answer (score 1):

You can clip the image this way.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var c = 0;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/200/200';

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (c++ % 2 == 0) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(img, 100, 100, 20, 20, 100, 100, 20, 20);
    btn.value = 'Unclip';
  }
  else {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    btn.value = 'Clip';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Clip" /><br />
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

### EDIT

When a user clicks on the `canvas`, you can get the exact co-ordinates of where the event happened and if the co-ordinates lies inside of the middle circle, you can toggle the whole image by using the same clipping method.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var c = 0;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://s25.postimg.org/cv29exevj/index.png';

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  context.drawImage(img, 80, 80, 40, 40, 80, 80, 40, 40);
}

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var y = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (x >= 80 && x <= 120 && y >= 80 && y <= 120) {
    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    } else {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(img, 80, 80, 40, 40, 80, 80, 40, 40);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: but mine was not an single image to cilp and redraw single.
I can creating that canvas dynamically with multiple circles which will get changed by user input.

you can see the Canvas image when user entered 5 

http://jsfiddle.net/5cau08n6/.

Comment: @Srinivas - Check out my edit, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @markE - Well, its 1:48AM here, I was about to pass out and I saw this question, so had to answer it. Actually, in comments below his main post he said that he is using this specific image, so I used it.

Comment: It's  the same thing as original. The only change that i see was instead of button you are using on click event of canvas.

See you are using the image that i have shown in Js fiddle.
but in may case i am actually generating that as a canvas.

and you clearing the canvas and re-drawing the image. i want to do it in a way like Show/ hide part of canvas instead of clear and redraw.

Comment: @Srinivas - Your question is still not clear to me. Please tell me exactly what part you want to show / hide.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ufrnn2jw/

requirement is when user clicks on Center circle i want to toggle the remaining part of canvas.

and when user clicks on outer circles i need to change the value of center circle

Comment: you do that by redrawing.

Comment: In addition to being blindingly fast, It's actually more memory efficient than 2 images I dont see what the reservations are